# How Many Ways May Apposition Occur in English?

Tags: appositives

Nearly invariably, appositives are presented as involving a noun phrase or noun clause modifying or supplementing a noun phrase.  Usually, the discussion strongly implies that appositives occur only with nouns (see, e.g., [Appositives—What They Are and How to Use Them](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/appositive/) and [Appositives](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html)).  I've seen only one substantive discussion of adjective-type appositives (see, e.g., [Appositive Adjectives](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-appositive-adjective-1688999)).

But, it seems to me that there are many different ways in which appositive phrases occur. Adjectival, adverbial and verb phrases all seem capable of participating in appositional behavior.  Consider the following examples:

|  | Example | Participants |
| --- | --- | --- |
| (A) | The future of mankind, [our descendants], will face great challenges. | *NP mod NP* |
| (B) | The Middle Ages, [dark and bleak], seem like a gap in the march of progress. | *AdjP mod NP* |
| (C) | The man was satisfied, [happy with the candidate]. | *AdjP mod Participial Phrase* |
| (D) | The Senator quickly stood, [nearly leapt], from his seat. | *VP mod VP* |
| (E) | The sad boy slowly, [hesitantly], approached his teacher. | *AdvP mod AdvP* |

I believe Huddleston and Pullum might describe most of these as cases of supplementation. See, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, Ch. 15, §5.

I'm interested in how these would be described by an English teacher. Are these appositive phrases?  If not, how are these constructs described in the *traditional parlance* of English grammar?

Comment: This currently asks too many questions to produce a single fact-based answer. Besides, it looks like you've already found out that apposition has a range of definitions depending on who you ask - making the final question (how to describe the constructions listed in 'traditional parlance') unlikely to have one correct answer.

Comment: The story of Wagner's *Das Rheingold* begins in, literally *in*, the Rhine river.

Comment: When I was teaching ESL, I would have called all these phrases appositives.